# React Default Padding for Link

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

[Image of Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5tnQ.png)

As you can see in the image provided for the button, even when there is 0 margin and padding provided, it still seems to create some padding on the bottom. I am using a link to create this button and it is a custom component.

Code for button:

```
<Link
      className={`tracking-wide rounded-full font-bold md:text-lg text-2xl text-center ${className}`}
      to={target}
      onClick={toClick}
    >
      {name}
    </Link>
```

Here is how I am referring to it:

```
<FilledButton
              name="Login"
              className="mx-2 bg-secondary text-neutralLight py-0 px-7 b-0 hover:bg-opacity-95 hover:opacity-95"
              target="/login"
            />
```

Any help on how to make the text exactly centered. For context this is being used in a navbar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's actually a padding but some leading (line height) for the text. I would try to use `flex` `justify-center` and `item-center` to try to center that button text, if you modify the leading it may work too but I'd guess it would be a bit of a hassle and may not respond properly. Hope this helps.